# Is it correct using "GET" as method for changing data in REST API

Tags: php, rest, api, logic

I'm creating a small application for double opt-in purposes, the user has to click on a link in a email, but this sends a GET HTTP request to my REST API. But logically requesting a REST API with GET results in **getting** data instead of **setting** data.

I have tried to use a

```
<form method="post" action="x.x.x.x/api/optin/double/"></form>
```

element to set the method to POST and creating an input element:

```
<input name="method" value="put" style="display:none">
```

to"set the method by a parameter.
But this does not seem to be the right solution.

I could create a file("accepteddooubleoptin.php") for that purpose but I'm not sure if that is the right solution. Or am I totally miss understanding the REST purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There's no practical way to have a link in an email result in a `POST` request. The best you could do is send them to a page which displays a button which they must click which generates the `POST` request, but it's debatable whether you would want this flow for the user as opposed to a single click in their email.
2. The request is basically *idempotent*, i.e. even if the user clicks multiple times, it still results in them simply being in the opted-in state, so no state is *repeatedly* modified (as opposed to a new post being generated every time you `POST` to `/blog/posts`, for example).

In conclusion, it's alright, just use the `GET` request.

Comment: For 1, you could pretty easily have a page that triggers a `POST` request using javascript without the user pressing a button. (Though I agree with your answer generally)

Comment: Couldn't i also have as @TheGentleman said a page that shows the user, that he successfully  made the double opt in and trigger the requests via PHP?

Comment: @Mario And the point of that being…? The end result is the same, you'll still make a GET request which results in the user being opted in. You're just being overly dogmatic about implementation details of REST.

Comment: @deceze: Well, the difference is the attack vector. A get link can be embedded into an image and sent via mail, causing the person who views the mail to trigger it and execute it with his permission (i.e. mutate some state). A link to a non-changing page can't do that and will only do the mutation of the state once the java script triggers for the reload. CSRF is an issue in the real world

Comment: @Tseng Mario described a technique in which the PHP handling the GET request would trigger a POST request behind the scenes… that doesn't protect anything against anything.

Comment: Eh no. Maybe you reread his question. He wants to perform an operation, which changes something (opt-in/opt-out) and was using get +form post to send it before and wants to make it as get only. Which is just plain wrong and will trigger false positives and susceptible for cross-site request forgery (XSRF/CSRF). Also some Spam/Anti-Virus solutions will **CALL** the link in an email to check if the target contains malicious code. In this case the anit-virus solution WILL perform the double-opt-in (or an opt-out) operation without the user interacting it

Comment: This on other side, could allow people to lets say, enter your email address at that page, when the mail arrives and scans it, double-opt-ins you, without your consent. So even if you delete the mail you will still be signed in. Since GDPR (DSGVO) its effectively a violation of the GDPR and illegal. This happened already when the GDPR got effective, a lot of companies sending crappy programmed GDPR opt-ins which opt-in people via get request, resulting in anti-virus solutions calling the link. REST or not, GET operations shouldn't modify a state in a **well written** web application

Comment: @Tseng It wasn't clear to what exactly to were responding. Since you appear chronologically in the comments here, I expected you to respond to my last comment, not my answer. – Yes, you are right, the link may be triggered inadvertently. I don't think CSRF is a huge concern, since the link (should be) uses a random string, which an attacker can't replicate, unless they can also receive the email, and in that case they'll just be signing themselves up for a newsletter anyway.

Comment: Anti-Virus solutions **can and will still trigger** this operations when they scan the email and the links inside it. There should always be an "subscribe" or "unsubscribe" button on the target page, which triggers an post operation to avoid such issues

Comment: After rereading your answer I realized that its a bit confusing and can be read two ways. You did write _even if the user clicks multiple times_. However its unclear if it refers to "multiple clicks on the email link" or "multiple clicks on the form submit button". Former implies its okay for "GET" to "modify state and opt-in the user without clicking another button", while the later rather implies "its okay to redirect the user to a website where he has to click a button to opt-in". For me it did (and does) read as the former.

Answer (score 2):

`GET` is a perfectly acceptable way to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish.

It's not a bad instinct to want to use your `GET`/`POST`/`PATCH`/`DELETE` verbs in their most literal sense, but this is one case where the technology (i.e., modern email clients) all but makes the decision for you. And there's nothing wrong with that.

See this [short post from Campaign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2007/11/how-forms-perform-in-html-emai/) explaining what it looks like when you try to generate a `POST` request in an email. In short, the user's email client gets weirded out *at best*.

In fact, if you take a look at account verification or password reset emails from any popular web service (even StackOverflow, for example), you'll find you're in good company in that they use links with query strings to pass tokens or account identifiers in order to drop the user into the right workflow on their sites.

If you're still uncomfortable with the idea of "setting" a value via `GET`, you might think of it more like your user is clicking their link to "get" the appropriate form through which they ultimately "set" their preference.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it correct using “GET” as method for changing data in REST API

The important thing to understand about the standard meaning of GET is that it has [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) semantics.  Here is how Fielding described the matter [in 2002](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html).

> HTTP does not attempt to require the results of a GET to be safe.  What it does is require that the semantics of the operation be safe, and therefore it is a fault of the implementation, not the interface or the user of that interface, if anything happens as a result that causes loss of property (money, BTW, is considered property for the sake of this definition).

Because the semantics of the request are supposed to be safe, the email client is allowed to send a request before the recipient clicks on the link!  For instance, the client might pro-actively load the response into a cache so that the latency for the human being is reduced if the link does get clicked.

For a use case like "Opt In", you really need to be thinking about what liabilities you incur if that link is fetched without the explicit consent of the human being.

The right way to do it would be to use an unsafe request (like POST).

However, implementing Opt In the "right" way may have a significant impact on your acceptance rate; the business might prefer to accept the liability rather than losing the opportunities.